# How to show a child element on top of parent's sibling overlay

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an issue of z-index stacking on my react component. The codebase has been so complex, and when I tried to do suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511702/element-on-top-of-parents-sibling) it doesn't work. The simplified problem maybe like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/njevg6Lt/2/).

What I am trying to do is simply to make a background overlay when a sidebar menu is opened (by default it's hidden). This sidebar menu is the child of the top navbar. And the div overlay background is the sibling to the top navbar.

Something like this:

```
<div className="overlay" />
<TopNavbar>
  <SideMenuBar>
  </SideMenuBar>
</TopNavbar>
```

TopNavbar has z-index=900. 
If I set div overlay z-index to 901 and SideMenuBar z-index to 902, the div overlay will still cover all screen. 
If I set div overlay z-index to 900 it will cover the background, but the TopNavbar will not be covered.

The other question I wonder when I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511702/element-on-top-of-parents-sibling) is:
why is this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P3qwx/3/1) works fine while the z-index of span5 is less than span 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: Does my answer help you with this problem?If not,I will delete it or update it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case React portal will help to render the child element in DOM where you want as per your requirements so that you can handle the layering of element easily.

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node
>   that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component

Please follow this tutorial this will help you get out of this problem [click](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)